# Creating variables with numbers from filename

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, numbers, extract

I have a folder full of xls files, named data_00001 through data_10000. Each file has a dozen or so identically named tabs full of RV's. I am interested in reading all files and tabs and creating histograms of the RV's.

Is there a way to read in the last 5 digits of the file names and attached them to each tab name (which I saved as a variable)?

I used `regexp` to extract the number as a string and converted it to a double, and I used a for loop to save variable `X{1,k}`. How can I incorporate the saved double into this variable?

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of your code. You will get much more help that way

Comment: Why do you want to incorporate the number into the variable name? Indexed variables are much more easy to manipulate.

Comment: Agree, the user should be encouraged to use indexed cells instead.

Comment: I wanted to incorporate the number in the variable to easily ID the dataset, since the file numbers are not always in sequence.

Comment: So far I have: > myFolder = 'Z:\MyFiles\'; filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '.xls'); xlsFiles = dir(filePattern); for k = 1:length(xlsFiles) baseFileName = xlsFiles(k).name; fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName); fprintf('Now reading %s\n', fullFileName); Output_Data{k} = importdata(fullFileName); end > for i = 1: numel(xlsFiles) Digits = regexp(xlsFiles(i).name, 'Filename_(\d).xls', 'tokens'); Digits= Digits{1}; Number(i) = str2double(Digits); end –

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
filenames = ['data_00001','data_10000'];
nums = regexp(filenames, '[0-9]+', 'match');
tag = 'TAG';
for i=1:size(nums,2)
  eval(['A_' tag '_' sprintf("%s",nums{1,i}) ' = zeros(1)']);
end
```

It creates matrices (zero in this case) with variable names

```
A_TAG_00001 = 0
A_TAG_10000 = 0
```